# Why is Visual Studio 2013 loading a mismatching PDB from a different folder?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, symbols, pdb-files

When debugging a web application my Visual Studio 2013 loads old PDB symbols. Clearing the solution folder and `Temporary ASP.NET Files` only works once. The problem reappears as soon as I make another change. In details:

1. (Start VS)
2. Start the project using F5 => Breakpoints load
3. Make a change (e.g. add a whitespace)
4. Press F5 => Breakpoints do not load
5. Wait a little while (maybe 30sec). Press F5. Breakpoints load.

When the breakpoints do not load the Modules Window shows mismatched paths and sometimes it shows multiple versions of my DLL:

[image]

The old DLL and PDB version (1) is still loaded (load order 67). The new DLL (157) uses the old PDB version. In Process Explorer I see that the w3wp process has two AppDomains which apparently correspond to the two app versions. After a few seconds the old version is unloaded but of course the new DLL continues to use the old PDB.

In the file system under `Temporary ASP.NET Files` the DLLs and PDBs are correctly paired. Each pair has its own folder.

How can I make Visual Studio load matching PDBs? Alternatively, how can I make IIS unload the old app before it starts the new version and signals Visual Studio that it is OK to attach now?

Comment: Just a guess - in a fairly "large" application (web site actually), with nested (virtual application) sites, I work with, I experience same. Viewing the "status bar", the entire "nest" needs to finish recompiling before debugging. Random errors also pop until such time (errors are gone after x time/entire application is "ready"). Hth..